# Sending file from Server to Client java

Tags: java, sockets, server, client

When I'm sending a small file, everything works fine. But when I'm trying to send a file about 5 megabytes, server throws such exception: `java.net.socketexception: connection reset by peer: socket write error`.

This is a part of my Server:

```
try {          
    File myFile = new File("E:\\work\\java\\in.pdf");
    long len = myFile.length();
    byte[] mybytearray = new byte[(int) myFile.length()];
    output = new PrintStream(serviceSocket.getOutputStream());
    output.println(clientCounter + " " + len);

    bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(myFile));
    bis.read(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
    os = serviceSocket.getOutputStream();
    os.write(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
    os.flush();
    serviceSocket.close();
}
catch(IOException e) {
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're assuming that `read()` fills the buffer, and no doubt you're making the same mistake in the client as well. You have to loop.